# TYPO3: DataHandler::setHistory() and typoLink_URL()

Tags: typo3, datahandler

I would now like to 'combine' `DataHandler::setHistory()` and `typoLink_URL()` in order to get the URL of whatever has been changed.

For a simple page, the below snippet does the trick:

```
$conf['parameter'] = 55;
typoLink_URL($conf);
```

To account for foreign languages, typoLink_URL requires an addition parameter:

```
$conf['additionalParams'] = '&L=2';
```

Also, the URL of a page created by a plugin may be retrieved via an additional parameter, such as:

```
$conf['additionalParams'] = '&tx_ttnews[tt_news]=' . 2;
```

Is there a more generic way to get URLs? In other words, how do I find out the URL regardless of whether or not I know anything about the plugins installed?

Answer (score 0):

You get the URL of the current page. All the parameters will be given.

```
 $site_url = t3lib_div::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_REQUEST_URL');
```

You call could look like this:

```
$conf['additionalParams'] = substr(t3lib_div::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_REQUEST_URL'),strlen(t3lib_div::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_SITE_URL')));
```